# Doxygen documentation of boost::signals2 function signature

Tags: c++, boost, doxygen, boost-signals2

like in the title: does anyone know how to properly write Doxygen documentation of the signature of a boost::signals2

```cpp
/**
 * @brief aSignal
 * void   : aVoidReturn
 * int    : anInteger
 * doulbe : aDouble
 */
boost::signals2::signal<void(int,double)> aSignal;
```

Thaanks

Comment: Which version of doxygen? What did you try so far and where do you have problems?

Comment: @MarekR it actually works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OP says my solution from comment works I'm turning that to answer.

Basically problem is that arguments of signal do not have names, only types, so providing those names solves the issue:

```cpp
struct Foo
{
    /**
    * @brief aSignal
    * @param quantity number of items
    * @param weight mass of items
    */
    boost::signals2::signal<void(int quantity, double weight)> aSignal;
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ezvhcza8s